# Adding qualified XML element doesn't inherit namespace URI

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js, xml-namespaces, xmldom

How can I append an element with a ns-prefix to another and make it inherit namespaceURI mappings from document?

As an example: Instantiating a document parsing an XML string: The `pp:q` element inherits `namespaceURI == 'abc'` from `root` element, but appending a new element `pp:q` to `root`, the new element has `namespaceURI == null`

```
doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(
    '<root xmlns:pp="abc">'
       +'<pp:q/>'
       +'<q/>'
    +'</root>'
    ,'text/xml');
root = doc.firstChild;

x = root.getElementsByTagName("pp:q").item(0);
console.log(x.namespaceURI);       // logs abc

y = doc.createElement('pp:q')
root.appendChild(y)
console.log(y.namespaceURI);       //logs null
```

This example ran in `nodejs` using `xmldom` [library](https://github.com/jindw/xmldom)

[edited below in response to kjhughes]

I tried `createElementNS` too, but i feel there's something wrong this way too..
appending these lines to the code:

```
a = doc.createElementNS('abc', 'pp:q');
root.appendChild(a)
console.log(a.namespaceURI);       //abc --- i may say it works, 
                                   //even though i'm required using  
                                   //both prefix *and* namespaceURI manually
                                   //while for the parsed element (x)
                                   //a lookup has been succesfully issued
                                   // but ... 

a1 = doc.createElementNS('abc', 'xx:q');
root.appendChild(a1)
console.log(a1.namespaceURI);       //abc --- but prefix is xx! not according to xmlns declaration!

b = doc.createElementNS('xyz', 'VV:q');
root.appendChild(b)
console.log(b.namespaceURI);       //xyz  --- I can write anything!

console.log(String(doc));          //<root xmlns:pp="abc"><pp:q/><q/><pp:q/><xx:q/><VV:q/></root>
```

Comment: Did you try `a1 = doc.createElementNS('abc', 'q');`, if this results in an element `pp:q`?

Comment: ``a1 = doc.createElementNS('abc', 'q')`` ends up with ``a1.namespaceURI == 'abc'`` and an ``<q/>`` element !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the documentation of [document.createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement),

> var element = document.createElement(tagName);
>
> **element** is the created element object.
>
> **tagName** is a string that
>   specifies the type of element to be created. The nodeName of the
>   created element is initialized with the value of tagName. ***Don't use
>   qualified names (like "html:a") with this method***.

You should instead use [document.createElementNS()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElementNS).

**Update per question update:**

Be aware that the namespace itself is what's important, not the namespace prefix.  There is no obligation on the part of the API to use a specific namespace prefix when you are providing multiple prefixes for a given namespace.  Moreover, realize that `.namespaceURI` is the *namespace*, **not** the *namespace prefix*.

Comment: Ok, it's reasonable, but: #1:the prefix _is_ important when parsing an xml, as the namespace is looked up according to it.. #2:if i createElementNS and append like in last 2 examples (a1,b) the serialization looses ``.namespaceURI`` unless i manually-explicitally addAttributeNS according to the added element.. that's really awkward!

Comment: (1) The namespace prefix is arbitrary; mind your assumptions when using multiple, different namespace prefixes for the same namespace name.  (2) Take care to declare all namespace prefixes that you use.  I believe that when you fix your calls such that your document is [namespace-well-formed](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#Conformance) (`<root xmlns:pp="abc"><pp:q/><q/><pp:q/><xx:q/><VV:q/></root>` is *not*.), you will find the calls to be less awkward.

Comment: So, it means that the right way is to take _personally detailed_ care of everything using ``DOM`` apis, and, in this case, use ``element.lookupPrefix()`` and ``element.lookupNamespaceURI()`` to keep elements consistent with ``prefixes`` and ``namespaceURI``s, and.. this is why when an element is created with a ``NS`` that ``NS`` is not overwritable?

Comment: Let me finally ask to clarify: having ``xmlns:ns="abc"`` on ``root`` element and appending a ``createElementNS('abc', 'xxx')`` (``xxx`` without any prefix or with ``prefix != 'ns'``) i'll have ``<xxx/>`` with namespace ``abc`` .. when i serialize the dom to string and save it, `xxx`'s namespace is lost for next consumers. Is this how it is supposed to be, or i am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting confused, because you use `console.log(String(doc));` to output the XML. Use XML serializer instead: `console.log((new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(doc));`

Other points to keep in mind

1. Always use `createElementNS()` when creating elements that have a namespace URI (with or without a prefix).
2. The namespace prefix doesn't matter. What matters are the namespace URI and the corresponding namespace definition (that either binds the URI to a prefix or makes the namespace a default namespace).
3. If any element or attribute uses some prefix that prefix must be bound to a namespace URI. Otherwise the document will be (namespace) invalid.
4. Do not use mimetype `text/xml`, it will lead to serious encoding problems and is deprecated. Use `application/xml` - or in this case `application/xhtml+xml` - instead.